# Can't synchronise mongoose operation to return an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

As a part of an employee's app management, I want to separate the business logic database operations from my main application file.
The simplest operation is to read all the employees from the database using async/await to synchronize it:

```
module.exports.getEmployees = async () => {
    const employees = await Employee.find();
    return employees;
}
```

in my app.js I typed the following code:

```
const employee = require(__dirname + "/models/employee.js");

app.get("/employees", (req, res) => {
    const employeeList =  employee.getEmployees();
    employeeList.then(res.send(employeeList));
})
```

but still, the array shows up empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`then` clause in promise accepts a functions as an argument & this function has a parameter which holds the actual response.

Something like this -

```
new Promise().then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
});
```

You are doing `employeeList.then(res.send(employeeList));` which means the argument to then clause is `res.send()` which won't work.

Try this -

```
employeeList.then((list) => {
    // please note the response type here depends on the Content-Type set in the response Header
    res.send(list);
    // In case of normal http server, try this -
    res.send(JSON.stringify(list));
});
```

I hope this helps.